# Error Encountered using ".format"

Tags: python

This is the code I have so far

```
def Save_Scores():
    global score
    score=str(score)
    file=open("Class{}.txt",'a').format(group) 
    file.write("\n")
    file.write ("Name: "+name+"\n")
    file.write("Score: "+score+"/10\n")
    file.close()
quiz()
```

However I encounter this error when the function is ran

```
line 42, in Save_Scores
file=open("Class{}.txt",'a').format(group)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Comment: Did you mean `"Class{}.txt".format(group)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.format()` is a method on string objects, but you are trying to call it on a *file*. Apply it to the string you want to pass to the `open()` call:

```
file = open("Class{}.txt".format(group), 'a')
```

Other best practices you can apply here:

- Rather than use `score` as a global, make it an argument to your function, then pass it in when you call the function.
- You also use `name` and `group` as globals, these should be arguments here too.
- Make use of the `with` statement to have Python close the file for you.
- You can use string formatting on the data you write to the file too, rather than use concatenation.

With those changes your function would look like this:

```
def Save_Scores(group, name, score):
    with open("Class{}.txt".format(group), 'a') as file:
        file.write("\nName: {}\nScore: {}/10\n".format(name, score))
```